# mount root (/) again after mistake, without /etc/

Tags: linux, mount, root, partition-recovery, fdisk

I think I accidentally mounted **/dev/hde1** to **/** after formatting another disk with

```
 mkdosfs -F 32 -I /dev/hde1
```

**/dev/hdc1** should be mounted on **/**
but now there is no way to remount it again since **/etc/fstab** is either readable nor writable, **/** is empty as the disk **/dev/hde1** is.
How do I remount **/dev/hdc1** without **/etc/**

`fdisk -l` gives only info about /dev/hde (but I already disconnected it)
it seems old information
`umount /dev/hde` says it is not mounted after all, possibly nothing is mounted to **/**

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

  22     0  976554308 hdc
  22     1    2048000 hdc1
  22     2     256000 hdc2
  22     3          1 hdc3
  22     5  974242112 hdc5
  31     0       1024 mtdblock0
  31     1      64496 mtdblock1
  33     0  976554308 hde
  33     1  976551156 hde1
 254     0  974225408 dm-0
   8    16 1953514584 sdb
   8    17 1953512448 sdb1
   8    32  390711384 sdc
   8    33   40161280 sdc1
   8    34  350546332 sdc2


$ mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on /initrd type ext2 (rw)
tmpfs on /USB type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/hdc1 on / type ext3 (ro,data=journal)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
tmpfs on /ramfs type ramfs (rw)
/dev/c/c on /c type ext3 (rw,noatime,data=ordered,usrquota,grpquota)
usbfs on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw)
/dev/sda2 on /USB/USB_HDD_1 type ext3 (ro,noatime,data=journal)
```

is how it should be, but also old information

I tried:

```
$ mount /dev/hdc1 / -t ext3
can't create lock file /etc/mtab~2509: No such file or directory (use -n flag to override)

$ mount /dev/hdc1 / -t ext3 -n
mount: /dev/hdc1 is not a block device, and stat fails?
```

It is a closed system (readynas) and stores all my pictures
these are still accessible, but I cannot mount new external disks to copy the pictures to, although dmesg sees the disk, I cannot mount it the normal way either

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting it? Since you didn't edit the `/etc/fstab` file, it should reset the mount points automatically when it reboots. Optionally, you can also try `umount /dev/hde1` to remove just that one mount.

Comment: the stuff on it is so precious that since i still have ssh contact (i cannot gain new access either way) that i dare not to reboot, as i don't know if it will boot again and i am locked out. umount does say it isn't mounted

Comment: Did you edit the `/etc/fstab` file? If not, reboot and get access to the normal `/` partition

Comment: i didn't manually, don't you think i could have screwed up the partition table, which i can not access anymore once rebooted?

Comment: the disk is not easy to attach to another system to retrieve the data, thats why i don't dare to screw up more as i still have access now

Comment: Fstab has nothing to do with the partition table

Comment: i get that but as fdisk -l shows only one instance, ie /dev/hde, which does not even exist this moment, it makes me worry  i seem to also not be root anymore, but uid 0, and ofcourse there is also no access to /etc/passwd.  possibly the only way is jump in the deep and try to reboot

Comment: So, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps:**

- Create a new directory in an existing directory you can still access.
- `mount` this new directory to `/dev/hdc1`.

*Presumably the full `/` tree, including `/etc`, should then be accessible through the* ad hoc *mountpoint.*

- Check `/etc/fstab` for correctness, editing it to be correct if it's not.
- Reboot.

Comment: it doesn't work:  `$ mount /dev/hdc1 disk/ -t ext3 -n  
mount: /dev/hdc1 is not a block device, and stat fails?`

Comment: @nielswebwerk Oohf, of course -- unmounting `/` means `/dev` isn't accessible for the OS to find. What about rebooting to a LiveCD / LiveUSB to inspect `/etc/fstab`?  It's looking like taking the reboot plunge, one way or the other, may be the only option.

Comment: This is confusing.  If `/` has been hidden by having something mounted over it, `/bin` and `/proc` shouldn't be accessible, either, and yet `cat /proc/partitions` worked.